# Jekyll error: undefined method ancestors for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, jekyll

My post template in jekyll renders a presentation either of Google slides or of a jupyter notebook html. For this purpose, I use the markdown structure shown below:

```
---
layout: post
title: title
date: 2018-10-28 00:00:00 -0500
categories: category
author: author
medium: jupyter
link: [//]: # (Here I insert the presentation url)
lang: en
---

<div>
    {% if page.medium == 'jupyter' %}
        {% include jupyter.html link=page.link %}
    {% elsif page.medium == 'gslides' %}
        {% include gslides.html link=page.link %}
    {% else %}
        {% include nodata.html %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

This generates the desired result. However, during the bundle creation, jekyll outputs this error for each post file:

```
Error: A Liquid tag in the excerpt of ./file.markdown couldn't be parsed.
Error: could not read file ./file.markdown: undefined method `ancestors' for nil:NilClass
```

I have already looked for any syntax errors along with this and other files, and all seems to be ok. Does someone has gone through a similar problem?

EDIT: I've taken the elif and the else clause of the statement, only then the problem ceases.

Comment: did you answer your own question?  If so you may want to add your solution as an answer.

Comment: No, I just wanted to point out more specifically how the error shows up. I still intend to use the elif and else clause

Comment: I am having the same problem. My markup looks similar. Which Jekyll version are you using?